# Permission denied when browsing for files using Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: permissions

I have two partitions that I mount during boot, which aren't on my boot drive (SSD), but on internal HDD. I can access the files fine using Nautilus, I can edit them (e.g. with PhpStorm) but when I try to open a file using the "browse" functionality (e.g. when uploading a file using Firefox or opening a repository in GitKraken) I get a "permission denied" error. I can't even upload a picture of the problem here, so this is what it says:

```
Could not read the contents of www.
Error opening directory '/media/www': Permission denied
```

I really don't know what's wrong. Anyone have an idea?

The drives in question are the last 2 lines in my fstab file:

**/etc/fstab**

```
UUID=5221e846-702d-47b0-bc92-aad063ae8fcd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=6C58-64C5  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D398F590634270 /media/www auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D2EB44D1D7F3E0 /media/wouter auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

**mount | grep /dev/sd**

```
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sda2 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb3 on /media/www type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,x-gvfs-show)
/dev/sdb2 on /media/wouter type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,x-gvfs-show)
```

Comment: Sorry! copy-paste error!  meant to say `mount | grep /dev/sd`...

Comment: @Fabby fixed it!

Comment: `/media/drive` does not exist...  So uploading from that location will never work: you need to upload from `/media/wouter`. Can you expand on what you're doing exactly before getting the error message?

Comment: @Fabby I'm sorry, I renamed the drive to "drive" for convenience, but it's actually "www", so it does exist. An example of what produces the error is when I want to, for example, add a photo to Facebook. When I browse for pictures and click on the drive label, it gives me the error. Another example is trying to open a git repo in GitKraken. When I browse for the repository and click the drive label: same error.

Comment: Could you change `auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show` to `ntfs-3g rw,inherit,permissions,streams_interface=windows,windows_names,compression,norecover,hide_dot_files,hide_hid_files,big_writes` for `www` and type `mount --all` after having edited the `/etc/fstab` and report back?

Comment: @Fabby I tried it, but it didn't help...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83602/discussion-between-fabby-and-wouter-c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem. It is a problem with Firefox' permissions.

1. Open "Ubuntu Software"
2. Find Firefox in the "Installed" tab and click on it
3. Choose "Permissions"
4. Make sure "Read/write files on removable storage devices" is on

Comment: This saved my day. I was not able browse file from chromium; so I set permission for chromium and then it worked. Thanks a lot bro :)

Comment: How does this work with `Lubuntu`?