# Permission denied with trying to read/write with an application on Ubuntu 18.04 and application does not show up in software manager

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, xubuntu

When using an application (in this case GitKraken) I'm getting permission denied when trying to read from a mounted drive.

While this can be fixed using the software manager GUI as per [Permission denied when browsing for files using Ubuntu 18.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471168/permission-denied-when-browsing-for-files-using-ubuntu-18-04), GitKraken doesn't show up in the software manager at all.

How do you give read/write permission to an application without using the software manager?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [apparmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) may be blocking access. The way to [fix this for packages installed via snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap) is to run

```
snap connect app-name:removable-media
```

However, GitKraken's snap install is not currently compatible with that plug:

```
> error: snap "gitkraken" has no plug named "removable-media"
```

The solution here would be to install gitkraken or similar applications from the .deb.